# How to measure latency in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, httprequest

Is there away to measure latency for one specific page?

Can I do some requests and calculate the average to know the latency?

Comment: I found an interesting solution in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469810/get-ping-latency-from-host-in-objective-c?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can.
You can use something like

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse {
    //Save [NSDate date] to a local var here
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse {
   //Use [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:*localVar*]
}
```

Do a bunch of these, average them out and you have your latency.
NSURLConnection is deprecated, I'm sure that this can be rewritten with NSURLSession.