# UIWebView taking too long to load a page as compared to Android?

Tags: ios, iphone

UIWebView taking too long to load a page as compared to Android? Can you tell me what could I have done wrong?

I am using the same web request, but its taking too long on iOS.

Comment: You can use a network proxy such as [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to examine the communications and potentially determine the problem.

Comment: Also try this [ping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25843488/1889814) and display it in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated it and came to know that there could be many reasons of it and its more dependent on individual case. However, one important thing that can be helpful is to use WKWeBView instead of UIWeBView as UIWebView is depreciated.