# Use of undeclared type "SimplePing"

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use `SimplePing` in my swift project. When I tried to do that (inspired from the second swift answer of this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469810/get-ping-latency-from-host-in-objective-c)), I got this error  `Use of undeclared type "SimplePing"` and `Use of undeclared type "SimplePingDelegate"`. I didn't find a pod for the SimplePing and it isn't exist by default in iOS.

How can I import it?

Comment: You need to add the SimplePing.h and SimplePing.m files to use those.

Comment: Have I to download it and add it in my swift application? If yes where exactly have I to put them (the package)

Comment: Just drag and drop those files to your project

Comment: Okay I did that but how can I import an objective c class into my view controller?

Comment: You need to use bridging header, please read this document for that https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Can you please make all this great informations in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimplePing is not a built-in library and there is no pod available for it right now. If you want to use that library, go ahead and download the `SimplePing.h` and `SimplePing.m` from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and just drag and drop it to your project.

Since your project is written in `Swift` and the library is in `Objective C`, you need to use a bridging header to expose the library to your swift classes.

You can read more about that on: [Objective C & Swift in Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)