# Using Simple Ping in swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use Apple's class: Simple Ping, but I can't get this working.

When I'm running example mac os x project it's working:

> 2015-06-17 00:03:22.569 SimplePing[20386:3133535] pinging 192.168.1.102
>
> 2015-06-17 00:03:22.569 SimplePing[20386:3133535] #0 sent
>
> 2015-06-17 00:03:22.570 SimplePing[20386:3133535] #0 received
>
> 2015-06-17 00:03:23.570 SimplePing[20386:3133535] #1 sent
>
> 2015-06-17 00:03:23.571 SimplePing[20386:3133535] #1 received

etc..

But when I do it from my ios (swift) app:

```
let pinger = SimplePing(hostName: "192.168.1.102")
pinger.delegate = self;
pinger.start()

do {
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate.distantFuture() as! NSDate)
} while(pinger != nil)
```

Not sure is do..while loop is needed - probably not needed. Anyway I tried without it too.

And I've added SimplePingDelegate to my class:

```
    func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didFailToSendPacket packet: NSData!, error: NSError!) {
        println("didFailToSendPacket")
    }

    func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("didFailWithError")
    }

    func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: NSData!) {
        println("didReceivePingResponsePacket")
    }

    func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didReceiveUnexpectedPacket packet: NSData!) {
        println("didReceiveUnexpectedPacket")
    }

    func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didSendPacket packet: NSData!) {
        println("didSendPacket")
    }

    func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didStartWithAddress address: NSData!) {
        println("didStartWithAddress")
    }
```

So it gives me output:

> 2015-06-17 00:32:12.368 Available[938:150352] CFHostStartInfoResolution
>
> 2015-06-17 00:32:12.374 Available[938:150352] >HostResolveCallback
>
> didStartWithAddress

other functions aren't called. Why?

Btw. I've also tried moving pinger into class variable like this:

```
var pinger: SimplePing?
```

No difference at all.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this doesn't work, but you can call the ping method yourself once the address is resolved.

A variable to tell you that you can start pinging:

```
var canStartPinging = false
```

The code that calls the ping:

```
let pinger = SimplePing(hostName: "www.apple.com")
pinger.delegate = self;
pinger.start()

do {
    if (canStartPinging) {
        pinger.sendPingWithData(nil)
    }
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate.distantFuture() as! NSDate)
} while(pinger != nil)
```

The `SimplePing` delegate method to wait for before you can start pinging:

```
func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing!, didStartWithAddress address: NSData!) {
    println("didStartWithAddress")
    canStartPinging = true
}
```

Comment: That was it! I missed sendPingWithData! Dunno why apple's example didn't have that and worked..

Comment: Can you please explain this snippet?                                                             do {
    if (canStartPinging) {
        pinger.sendPingWithData(nil) //For me it crashes here 
    }
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate.distantFuture() as! NSDate) //If i dont use this delegate never calls up
} while(pinger != nil)

Comment: @Artal - Do you know how we can ping multiple IPAddress with Simple Ping?

Comment: @iRahulDubey I've never really worked with this code in production. Just took a look at the Apple sample code for the purpose of this question. I suggest that you open a separate question and see if someone has the answer..